# Docker-compose running on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a website running on docker-compose. Everything works well I am using Jenkins as CI and when I committed code Jenkins manages docker-compose file to running app. 
I want to try Kubernetes and want to learn it. I did not find a good solution for docker-compose files. I saw Kompose but it did not works for me. Then I saw "Compose on Kubernetes" and find out this is only working for enterprise version. 
How do you transfer your containers to the Kubernetes? Especially docker-compose files. And how can I solve Kompose error? As you see in below this text, Kompose reject my project.

```
WARN Volume mount on the host "/home/fatih/Desktop/Django-DevOps-personal-website/pgdata" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
WARN Volume mount on the host "/home/fatih/Desktop/Django-DevOps-personal-website/config/nginx" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
WARN Volume mount on the host "/home/fatih/Desktop/Django-DevOps-personal-website/fatihkocnet" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host 
INFO Kubernetes file "db-service.yaml" created    
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-ssl-proxy-service.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-service.yaml" created   
INFO Kubernetes file "db-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "db-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-ssl-proxy-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-ssl-proxy-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "nginx-ssl-proxy-claim1-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-deployment.yaml" created 
INFO Kubernetes file "web-claim0-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml" created
```

You can check my source code from [here.](https://github.com/fatihkc/Django-DevOps-personal-website)

Comment: Compose on Kubernetes is not only enterprise anymore :) It was open-sourced at DockerCon EU '18 last week. https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. The warnings from Kompose are [because it doesn't currently support storing data on the host](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/855) so you could look to address that. You could use [`emptyDir` as a way of doing temporary storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) or look at [configuring `hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) but it depends what your target environment is. If you are looking to deploy to a cloud provider then you'd be best to look at options for their supported storage.

Another option would be to create a helm chart that uses the [official helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/) for postgres and maybe also for nginx, if you don't decide to switch to nginx-ingress. This could make sense if you're looking to use kubernetes for the long-term and want a deployment descriptor that takes advantage of kubernetes features and can be deployed on different types of kubernetes cluster.

If you are just looking to have a quick way to run things on a single machine then, as @[johnharris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559504/johnharris85) points out, [Compose on Kubernetes](https://github.com/docker/compose-on-kubernetes) would make a lot of sense for you.